# How create a angular module to Unity 3D?

Tags: javascript, angular, unity-webgl

I wish made an Angular module using Unity WebGL. Indeed nothing has already done on this topic and no module existed today.
However, I am little lost and I need help. It would be good if that module will develop to Angular 2. But I know Angular 1 so far.

Unity 3D export gave that:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-us">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Unity WebGL Player | Test Unity</title>
  <style>
    /* a style sheet needs to be present for cursor hiding and custom cursors to work. */
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas class="emscripten" id="canvas" oncontextmenu="event.preventDefault()" height="600px" width="960px"></canvas>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    var Module = {
      TOTAL_MEMORY: 268435456,
      errorhandler: null, // arguments: err, url, line. This function must return 'true' if the error is handled, otherwise 'false'
      compatibilitycheck: null,
      dataUrl: "Development/ExportMiniDev.data",
      codeUrl: "Development/ExportMiniDev.js",
      memUrl: "Development/ExportMiniDev.mem",

    };
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Could you please provide to me something to start. I already pass a lot of my time on this. If I succeed I will publish that module on Github.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing a Unity WebGL-project into an Angular2 component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43919161/importing-a-unity-webgl-project-into-an-angular2-component)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there are now a couple of libraries (I haven't tested them):

https://github.com/rgoddat/AngularUnity

https://github.com/cHullaert/ng-unity